# How do I put lines into a list from CSV using python

Tags: python, list, csv

I am new to Python (coming from PHP background) and I have a hard time figuring out how do I put each line of CSV into a list. I wrote this:

```
import csv
data=[]
reader = csv.reader(open("file.csv", "r"), delimiter=',')
for line in reader:
   if "DEFAULT" not in line:
      data+=line

print(data)
```

But when I print out data, I see that it's treated as one string. I want a list. I want to be able to loop and append every line that does not have "DEFAULT" in a given line. Then write to a new file.

Comment: that works as well...  should have put it in answer. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("file.csv", "r"), delimiter=',')
print([line for line in reader if 'DEFAULT' not in line])
```

or if it's easier to understand:

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("file.csv", "r"), delimiter=',')
data = [line for line in reader if 'DEFAULT' not in line]
print(data)
```

and of course the *ultimate* one-liner:

```
import csv
print([l for l in csv.reader(open("file.csv"), delimiter=',') if 'DEFAULT' not in l])
```